# Spring @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a question with Spring MVC RequestMapping annotation. need your help.

I have created one IPSLcontroller and i want that IPSLcontroller to  handle all request url.i have created two method in this controller.

1)handleLogoutRequest :- this method should invoke on below url.

2)handleRequest :- this method should invoke on all request url otherthan logout.

**http://localhost:9086/webapp/login**
or
**http://localhost:9086/webapp/add**
or
**http://localhost:9086/webapp/remove**

here is my sample code. but it's not working as expected.

```
@Controller
public class IPSLController {

    @RequestMapping(value={"/logout/*"},method = RequestMethod.POST)
    protected void handleLogoutRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        System.out
                .println("........................IPSLController logout request.......................................");

    }


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value={"/*"})
    protected void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        System.out
                .println("........................IPSLController all request Post.......................................");

    }
    }
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working as expected'?

Comment: I am looking for correct mapping value. above code is not working as expected. logout request is also coming to handleRequest method.

Comment: imho it works as expected. `/logout` is handled by your catch all, as to be expected that is what your mapping is. Next to that what you are doing is also a bad idea, don't write 1 controller to handle all the things, that is the role of the dispatcher servlet. The controller should be fine grained object.

Comment: Why don't you just let spring security handle the login/logout procedure? What you are trying here is already implemented just fine, and tested

Answer (score 0):

Well it is working the way it should. You have a mapping for `/*` and for `/logout/*`. So when you post to `/logout` it invokes the method for `/*`. I suspect that if you post to `/logout/something` it would invoke your logout handler.

If you want it to work, you cannot have a wildcard mapping for the second method. At least use `/something/*` so that spring can make a correct decision on mappings.

Comment: @Nester : This is not JAXRS.

Comment: @RossiRobinsion sorry, my bad)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a general Prefix for every controller you use, so you can differ between them better. Also you don´t need any "/"  for calls like this.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("ispl")
public class IPSLController {

@RequestMapping(value={"logout"},method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected void handleLogoutRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    System.out
            .println("........................IPSLController logout request.......................................");

}


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value={"hello"})
protected void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    System.out
            .println("........................IPSLController all request Post.......................................");

 }
}
```

If you now want to call them over a ServletRequest or with a restService or something similar you should declare them like this

```
@GET   
@Path("ispl/logout")
public void Method (HttpServletResponse ...)
```